# What does the phrase 'at the grassroots' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The president called upon the faculty, students, and alumni of IIM-Ahmedabad to continue to engage with creative minds from industry, business, entrepreneurs, society leaders and with those who work at the grassroots.

What is the meaning of the phrase 'at the grassroots' in the above sentence?

Answer (score -1):

The definition of "grassroots" [from Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/grassroots) is:

> 1. the common or ordinary people, especially as contrasted with the leadership or elite of a political party, social organization, etc.; the rank and file.

> 5. of, relating to, or involving the common people, especially as contrasted with or separable from an elite:

In this particular context, "grassroots" likely refers to members of the wider community or, in other words, the common folk who are not leaders. So, the president is calling upon the faculty, students, and alumni to engage both leaders and non-leaders.